# How to await/async with the .length method for an array?

Tags: flutter

I'm checking for a condition on login so I can route to different screens depending on the condition result. Basically if the array has a length == 0 I want to go to `Phone();`
Otherwise I want it to go to `HomeScreen()`  The condition is checking an array in `Firestore`for length. In my app  when the Length is not equal to zero if goes to `Phone();` momentarily before jumping to `HomeScreen`. I suppose my problem is a delay fetching the length in `Firestore` . I'm not sure how to go about implementing await/async in the condition statement...

```
case AuthStatus.signedIn: {
            print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
            if (userData.services.length==0) {
              print('Here I am!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
              print(userData.services.length);
              return Phone();

            } else {
              return
               HomeScreen();
            }

          } break;
```

Comment: The problem is not a delay when accessing .length but that the data changes after a short time (after it got fetched from firestore) and the widget rebuilds with the new data. You can try to use the Future you get when fetching the data with a future builder and show a loading spinner until you have the data.

Comment: why does the data change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, in some cases if you can't use async/ await, you can use then method for it.

```
case AuthStatus.signedIn: {
            print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
            int length;
            userData.services.length.then((dataLength){
                length = dataLength;
            });
            if (length==0) {
              print('Here I am!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
              print(length);
              return Phone();

            } else {
              return
               HomeScreen();
            }

          } break;
```

Comment: doesn't compile..`the method 'then' isn't defined for the class int`

Comment: Okay sorry.
I think your object is coming from firebase,

You can just put `.then((data){ <Your Method> });` after await method and it can prevent use for async and await.

Or you can follow this.

[Async programming in dart](https://medium.com/@takahirom/how-to-write-flutter-asynchronous-processing-22f845204f30)